# rename() no such file directory

Tags: php, rename

Here is my problem. I can get this script to run if I provide the name of the variable `$pdffilename = '130606PN627.pdf'` but if I set `$pdffilename = $_GET[pdfNewfilename]` the script fails and I get the following:

> Warning: rename(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PhpTut/data/UploadPDFFiles/130606PN627.pdf ,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PhpTut/data/PDFFiles/130606PN627.pdf ): No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PhpTut/data/update/update_expired_msds1.php on line 244

The script runs perfectly **up to `line 183`**. The only thing that doesn't work on this page is the `rename()` function and I can't figure out why this is happening since I see the correct file name in the WARNING and it will run if I manually set `$pdffilename = '130606PN627.pdf'` at line 188.

I'm baffled and have been searching for many hours trying to figure this out.

Could someone give me a hand with this? I would be very greatfull. Cheers.

Here is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css"/>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function nameExists() {
      alert('FILE NAME EXISTS IN\n\PDF MASTER DIRETCORY');
  }

  function reDirect() {
      location.href = '../update/expired_msds.php';
  }

  function redirect() {
      location.href = '../update/approve1.php';
  }

  function renameSuccess() {
      alert('FILE MOVED TO PDF MASTER DIRECTORY');
  }

  function noTargetFile() {
      alert('FILE MISSING FROM PDF UPLOAD DIRECTORY\n\PLEASE UPLOAD THE FILE');
  }

  function renameFail() {
      alert('MOVE FAILED');
  }
  </script>

  <?php

    require_once '../config.php';
    error_reporting();

    if (isset($_GET['pdfid'])&&($_GET['pdfupdateID'])&&($_GET['pdfNewfilename'])&&($_GET['manufacturer'])&&($_GET['productname'])&&($_GET['casno'])&&($_GET['effective'])&&($_GET['expires']    )){

      $id = '';
      $id = $_GET['pdfid'];
      $pdfupdateID = '';
      $pdfupdateID = $_GET['pdfupdateID'];
      $pdffilename = ' ';
      $pdffilename = $_GET['pdfNewfilename'];
      $manufacturer = '';
      $manufacturer = $_GET['manufacturer'];
      $name = '';
      $name = $_GET['productname'];
      $casno = '';
      $casno = $_GET['casno'];
      $effectivedate = '';
      $effectivedate = $_GET['effective'];
      $expiredate = '';
      $expiredate = $_GET['expires'];
      $status = '';
      $status = $_GET['status'];
      $obsol = '';
      $obsol = $_GET['obsol'];
      $cntrld = '';
      $cntrld = $_GET['cntrld'];
      $target = '';
      $target = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/PhpTut/data/UploadPDFFiles/$pdffilename";
      $newName = '';
      $newName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/PhpTut/data/PDFFiles/$pdffilename";
      $update = '';


      $update=$db->query("UPDATE `product_name` SET 

      `product_name`.`pdfprodname` = '$name',
      `product_name`.`pdfmanufacturer` = '$manufacturer',
      `product_name`.`pdfcasno` = '$casno',
      `product_name`.`pdffilename` = '$pdffilename',
      `product_name`.`pdfeffectdate` = '$effectivedate',       
      `product_name`.`pdfexpiredate` = '$expiredate',        
      `product_name`.`pdfcontrolled` = '$cntrld',
      `product_name`.`pdfstatus` = '$status',        

      `product_name`.`pdfupdatedate` = NOW()

      WHERE

      `product_name`.`pd_id` = $id");


    $select=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `product_name` WHERE `product_name`.`pd_id` = $id");

    $rows = $select->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($rows); 
    echo '</pre>';   


    //File is deleted from the "pdfupdate" table          
    $db->query("DELETE FROM `pdfupdate` WHERE `pdfupdate`.`pdf_id` = $id ");

    echo ($id), '<br>';
    echo ($pdffilename), '<br>';
    echo ($name), '<br>';
    echo ($manufacturer), '<br>';
    echo ($status), '<br>';
    echo ($casno), '<br>';
    echo ($effectivedate), '<br>';
    echo ($cntrld), '<br>';
    echo ($obsol), '<br>';
    echo ($expiredate), '<br>'; // This is line 183

    // $pdffilename = '130606PN627.pdf'; // Line 188 If I declare the variable here the file moves without errors
    $target = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/PhpTut/data/UploadPDFFiles/$pdffilename"; // Target folder

    // Checks to see if file exists in the "Target" folder
    if (!file_exists($target)) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        noTargetFile()
        redirect();
        </script>';
    }
    // Checks to see if file name is already in the "Destination Folder"
    $newName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/PhpTut/data/PDFFiles/$pdffilename"; // Destination folder
    if (file_exists($newName)) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        nameExists();
        redirect();
        </script>';
        }  else {
        //Moves $pdffilename from "Target" to "Destination"
        $renameResult = rename($target, $newName);     //This is line 244
    }
    if ($renameResult == true){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        renameSuccess();
        reDirect();
        </script>';
        } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        renameFail();
        redirect();
        </script>';
    }
  }    

  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It appears your directory/file listings are different. Check your error there. You will notice that paths are different. "uploadpdfiles" in the first string, "uploadfiles" in the second. Is this intentional?

Comment: before renaming the file check the permissions on directory, "if(is_writable($upload_path))"

Comment: what does [`realpath($pdffilename)`](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) give you?

Comment: jjonesdesign Yes the two strings are different and it is intentional as I am moving the file from the folder UploadPDFFiles to the folder PDFFiles.

Comment: Khan I have the permissions set up properly. As I mentioned in the description of the problem, I can set the variable $pdffilename = '130606PN627.pdf' and the file moves from the folder "UploadPDFFiles" to the folder "PDFFiles" without a problem. The problem seems to be in assigning the value of the varialbe $pdffilename.

Comment: Darren: When I echo realpath($pdffilename) I don't get a result. I can scandir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/PhpTut/data/UploadPDFFiles"); and see the file '130606PN627.pdf' in the directory array.

Comment: Khan I checked the  "if(is_writable($upload_path))" for both the file "pdffilename" and the path "$target = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/PhpTut/data/UploadPDFFiles". The file ($pdffilename) is "NOT WRITEABLE" but the path ($target) "IS WRITEBALE". I'm looking around the web to see if I can find out what makes a file "NOT WRITEABLE". Any suggestions? Thanks for the clues.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who tried to work through this problem. I have found the answer. It has nothing to do with permissions and was actually a problem with the search that I was doing. I have found that I can reproduce the error and remove it depending on how I search my data and the information that I pass using the URL. Your suggestions made me go back over my notes and work through it again and that's when I found the answer. Thanks again.